# Generics cannot convert error java

Tags: java, generics

```
List<? extends Number> ls = new ArrayList<Number>(); //(1)
Map <String,List<? extends Number>> mp = new HashMap<String,List<Number>>(); //(2)
Map <String,List<? extends Number>> mp = new HashMap<String,List<? extends Number>>(); //(3)
```

I can do (1) and (3) but not (2).

If I can do (1) why I am getting an error when doing (2)

Comment: If you're using java 7+ you can just do `new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though a `List<Number>` is a `List<? extends Number>`, a `HashMap<String, List<Number>>` is not a `Map<String, List<? extends Number>`, because Java's generics are invariant.  This is the same thing that makes [a `List<Dog>` not assignable to a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), even if `Dog` extends `Animal`.  Here, `List<Number>` plays the part of the `Dog` and `List<? extends Number>` plays the part of the `Animal`.

`List<Number>` can't match `List<? extends Number>` when used as a type parameter.

You can get (2) to compile by introducing a wildcard:  Change

```
Map <String,List<? extends Number>> mp = new HashMap<String,List<Number>>();
```

to

```
Map <String, ? extends List<? extends Number>> mp = new HashMap<String,List<Number>>();
```